# why does access 2010 with postgresql odbc driver call IDENT_CURRENT?

Tags: ms-access, postgresql, odbc, ms-access-2010

I am migrating an access 2003 application to access 2010. The application uses the postgres odbc driver to access its data.

On access 2010 it tries to use the IDENT_CURRENT function on the postgresql server (as seen with wireshark) to identify the id of a recently inserted row ... Unfortunately IDENT_CURRENT is not a function supported by postgresql as far as I know ...

I am using the latest postgresql ODBC driver (9.0) with a postgresql 8.3 database.

Comment: I was able to solve my particular problem by teaching postgres how todo IDENT_CURRENT for our tables (where the primary key is always stored in a column with the name <table>_id) but this is not really a nice solution I think.  

   CREATE FUNCTION IDENT_CURRENT(name) RETURNS BIGINT AS $$
         SELECT CURRVAL(
           regexp_replace(
              $1, 
              '.+public[."]+([^"]+)"?',E'\\1_\\1_id_seq'
           )
         );
   $$ LANGUAGE SQL;

Answer (score 1):

Using [`currval`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html) is the right way to go (emphasis mine):

> Return the value most recently obtained by `nextval` for this sequence in the current session. (An error is reported if `nextval` has never been called for this sequence in this session.) Because this **is returning a session-local value, it gives a predictable answer** whether or not other sessions have executed `nextval` since the current session did.

And wrapping it up in an `IDENT_CURRENT` function is a perfectly reasonable porting technique.

You could also use [`RETURNING id`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html) on your `INSERT` statements (again, emphasis mine):

> The optional `RETURNING` clause causes `INSERT` to compute and return value(s) based on each row actually inserted. This is primarily useful for obtaining values that were supplied by defaults, such as **a serial sequence number**.

That might be a bit quicker and cleaner but you'd still have some portability issues. OTOH, I think you're going to have portability issues no matter what you do.

Comment: I am aware of how to slove the problem on an sql level, I am just wondering why M$ Access 2010 with the Postgresql ODBC tries to use M$ SQL server commands on the postgresql database ... the same database running on Access 2003 does not exhibit this issue.

Comment: @Tobi: Is it Access, ODBC, the PostgreSQL ODBC driver, or your application that is trying to use `IDENT_CURRENT`. You'd think that lots of people use Access and ODBC with PostgreSQL so I'd guess that the problem is somewhere in your application but I could be wrong.

Comment: it is access ... with a rather complex form (one embedded inside another) ... the application works fine with acccess 2003 and the 8.4 odbc driver ... the odd behaviour start when switching to 2010 with the 9.0 odbc driver ...

Comment: @Tobi: Sorry, I don't know that much about Access (good for me, not for you). On the upside, you have a working kludge in place; on the downside, a kludge is a kludge. I added a couple Access tag for you, hopefully they will draw the attention of someone that knows something about Access.

Comment: I would think more people would use PostgreSQL with Access, but after SQL Server, Oracle and MySQL seem to me to be the most common. I have been a fan of PostgreSQL for a long time, since it matured as a full-fledged database long before MySQL did (PostgreSQL was mature when MySQL was still a toy with no engine-level foreign-key constraints!). But I've never had an opportunity to use it, unfortunately.

Comment: It seems to me that the driver is to blame, not Access.

Comment: Are you sure it is the driver and not your application or Access? I'm pretty certain that lots of people use the PostgreSQL ODBC driver and pulling out the last ID is a pretty common operation. I have a hard time believing that a bug of this nature in the driver would last long, PostgreSQL is known for being pretty solid.